# Make masterpage as generic for all site collection and sites in SP2013

Tags: master-page, branding

We have created a masterpage by editing the seattle.master. It is applied to the present site.

We want to apply this master page for all sites present in the web application.

Also, whenever we create a new site collection or new site, it should inherit this masterpage. Is this possible in SharePoint 2013?

Comment: Are you creating the site collection from custom site definition or using the OOB site definition?

Comment: Right now using the SP2013 designer we have edited the file. But are open to any possible solution

Answer (score 1):

You will need to use feature stapling to apply master page to newly created site collections.

> Feature Stapling has two features. A "Stapler" feature which staples
>   another feature to the site definition and the "Staplee" feature which
>   will be stapled

See more at http://www.mssharepointtips.com/tip.asp?id=1065
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kunal_mukherjee/archive/2011/01/11/feature-stapling-in-sharepoint-2010.aspx

However, you may need to write a console app  or PowerShell script to update already existing sites.

Comment: Presently when we use designer to edit masterpage, we are only updating the root site's masterpage and not the site collection, right? I say this because, when we create a new site subsite then it doesnot inherit the same edited masterpage

Comment: How are you changing the master page of the site collection?

Comment: Do you mean root site of sitecolelction? How can you apply masterpage to sitecollection?

Comment: Yes the root site. If it is a publishing site then there is option to "Reset all subsites to inherit this site master page setting" when you try to change the master page in UI

Comment: Can we get this options by enabling any feature on team site ?

Comment: Just checked. This option does not show up even after turning on both Publishing features in site and web level.

Comment: Yes. And when I create publishing site then by default the subsites inherit the parent sites mastetpage

Comment: Ok now my concern is that if I use feature stapling on a team site then every site collection (root site )will get the correct mastetpage. But the sub sites will not inherit this masterpage unless it is a publishing template

Comment: If the sub site is created from team site then the feature will get called and inside it the code can be written to set its master page. Whether a sub site or site collection is created from team site , the feature will get called.

Comment: Can you tell me if this logic can be achieved:- Build an event receiver at web applciaiton level that checks if the new site/sitecollection is created and set its masterpage from the sitecoolection1\rootweb source.

Comment: Yes a web application stapler feature and a staplee feature will be needed. However, if you intend to create a standalone web application feature, then that won't do it.

Comment: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94509/logic-to-set-master-page-for-all-sites-in-web-application Please check this updated link